# Div slant implementation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a `div` which can slant. Here is the code, but it's not working when I style it. CSS implementation works fine without any issues not sure what is the error with style parameter.

https://jsfiddle.net/vytcqbyd/

```
<div style="display:block; 
background-color:yellow; 
height:20px; 
width:1px; 
-ms-transform: rotate(20deg); 
-webkit-transform: rotate(20deg); 
transform: rotate(20deg); 
transform-origin: bottom left;">

</div>
```

CSS implementation:-

https://jsfiddle.net/4j8n45zz/1/

Comment: Which part is not working? Only real difference I notice is that one is larger than the other, but that's because of the different dimensions. They're both slanted...

Comment: Everything seems correct, line is not visible as height and width are smaller.

Comment: You will need glasses :P

Comment: Change it to `background-color:red` and you'll see it better.

Comment: You have different heights and widths in your examples, thats why they look different.

Comment: Also keep in mind rotating changes the absolute height and width of the element, skewX only changes the width of the element and keeps the vertical height intact.

Comment: Yeah, slanting is not the same as rotating. By the way, if you're going to do the thing with the prefixes, you will need to prefix the transform-origin as well.

Comment: Sorry, its working, just 'its tiny that I did not notice.